# Operating system in Ada

Tags: operating-system, ada

I wonder if anyone know any simple design, but a very simple operating system written in Ada
Or if possible, give an example, thank you.

Comment: See also this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ada/browse_frm/thread/dea2d62ab1462538).

Comment: ...assuming you have a Google account.

Comment: I see Trashgod found my thread on google on the same topic!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is also TAMP: https://github.com/Lucretia/tamp

But it's not in a status that you could call it OS.

Answer (score 13):

While there have been a number of hopeful starts, the only OS written in Ada I'm aware of that has achieved some semblance of completeness is [MaRTE OS](http://marte.unican.es), which is designed as a "a Hard Real-Time Operating System for embedded applications".

Answer (score 4):

The Army Secure Operating System (ASOS) was written almost entirely in Ada. It was designed to meet Orange Book A1 protection requirements, support Ada applications more directly, and run on a commodity Sun3. The total software was 55,000 lines of code. It even had checkpointing/restore and later a secure RDBMS.

http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/poirot3/Oakland/sp/PAPERS/00044288.PDF

Comment: The link is dead  :(

Comment: The best work on high-assurance security of that time was sometimes published in ACM and IEEE with paywalls. That was only free copy of final report. However, the intro will tell you plenty. In case you have access, I also include a link to the one with specs & verification.

Comment: Thanks :-) for the paper !

Answer (score 3):

Well, I actually know of several custom ones done for small embedded systems, but none are available for public viewing. Sadly, a lot of good Ada work has been hidden away from the public due to the military/avionics niche it has been done in.

[RTEMS](http://www.rtems.com/) has been available in both Ada and C source forms [since the mid-1990s](https://lists.rtems.org/pipermail/users/2004-September/010687.html).

Comment: History of RTEMS: http://www.rtems.com/ml/rtems-users/2004/september/msg00064.html